# ¿Cómo mostrar en LCD el valor de la tecla presionada de teclado matricial?

Tags: c, ccs

Al presionar un botón del teclado matricial, requiero imprimirlo en una pantalla LCD. Se emplea el microcontrolador MSP432 desarrollando el código en CCS.
Se desea extraer el valor de la tecla presionada para mostrarlo en la pantalla

```
void Tecla_identificada(int bandera){
char dato;
__delay_cycles(500000);
if(bandera==1){
printf("Tecla presionada: %c, en ASCII: %d,\n",
tecla[dato_ren][dato_col],tecla[dato_ren][dato_col]);
dato=dato_ren * 4 + dato_col;
dato &= 0x07; /* BITS 2-0 */
P2->OUT |= dato;
__delay_cycles(900000);
P2->OUT &=~dato;

}
LCD_inicializacion();
        for (;;){  /* Limpia display */
            LCD_comando(1);
            delay_ms(500);
            LCD_comando(0x80);  /* Configura cursor en el inicio de 1ra línea */
            
            LCD_dato('T');   /* escribe texto" */
            LCD_dato('e');
            LCD_dato('c');
            LCD_dato('l');
            LCD_dato('a');
            LCD_dato(' ');
            LCD_dato('%c');

            delay_ms(1000);
        }
}
```

%C al ser el numero de la tecla presionada, se requiere asignar un valor para escribir en la LCD.

Comment: No entiendo lo que estás preguntando: ¿ Error de compilación ? ¿ Que error ? ¿ En que línea ? ¿ Comportamiento inesperado ? Por favor, consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: El valor %C en consola me muestra la tecla que ha sido activada, ese mismo valor lo requiero escribir en la pantalla LCD.

Comment: Vale. Que ya te has mirado toda la documentación y has hecho todas las pruebas imaginables, y al final desistes y quieres que otro lo haga para tí. Ha quedado claro.

Comment: En realidad la propuesta de la lógica está ahí, sólo busco que alguien con un poco de experiencia sobre el tema esté en disposición de ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Vale tengo varias preguntas, el prototipo de LCD_dato cual es? Si directamente puedes escribir una cadena de caracteres esto es: "Hola". Asumire que puedes hacer eso.

Asumo tambien que en **`tecla[][]`** tienes guardado el ascii de cada caracter que tienes en el teclado, no?

De ser asi, pues simplmente al igual que haces el llamado de **`printf`** de

```
tecla[dato_ren][dato_col] podrias hacer: 

LCD_dato(tecla[dato_ren][dato_col]);
```

Por caso contrario si tienes guardado en tecla es el numero en *dec/hex* correspodiente a la tecla que presionaste. Podrias tomar otro camino. Pero bueno, me detendre aqui para conocer mas sobre tu caso.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La zona de respuestas, se utiliza cuando ya tenemos claro el escenario y no requiere de participación de quien ha preguntado. Para esto existe la zona de comentarios. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Comment: Hola, no podia agregar comentarios porque me pedia tener 50 de reputacion para contestar.